# I keep getting an integrity error while trying to create an appointment object from my django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I created an appointment model that has foreign key relationships with a couple of other models in my database. The Doctor model has a one-to-one relationship with the User model. The User model extends from the built-in django AbstractUser class

Below is the code for my appointment model:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    symptoms = models.ForeignKey(Symptom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    diagnosis = models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} - {self.doctor.user.username} - {self.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}"
```

and below is the code for the Doctor and User models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, help_text='Phone Number')
    is_user = models.BooleanField('Is User', default=False)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField('Is Doctor', default=False)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text='DesCription')
    category = MultiSelectField(choices=DIAGNOSIS, max_choices=5, max_length=1000, help_text='Category')
    experience = models.IntegerField(help_text='Experience')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Below is the code for the symptoms and diagnosis models:

```
class Symptom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Diagnosis'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Diagnosis'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is the error I keep getting when I try to create an appointment object from my django admin panel:
IntegrityError at /admin/core/appointment/add/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

I tried creating an appointment object and expected an appointment object to be created in my database but that didn't happen. I even deleted my database and re-populated it with new data but it's still giving the same error.

Also I was able to select objects from the related models while trying to create the appointment object
[Screenshot of an attempt to create an appointment object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgjnX.png)

And this was the result
[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrHET.png)

Comment: did you also define symptoms foreign key? because you just mention doctor and user

Comment: Yes. I'll modify the question and add the code for the remaining models @Razenstein

Comment: What is missing when you create your model: the `user`, the `doctor`, the `symptoms` or the `diagnosis`?

Comment: @LajosArpad when I try to create the Appointment model, the error is thrown then when I try to go back to the main admin page, there is a little inscription at the top of the page saying 'Appointment with ID “1” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?'

Comment: It was not deleted. It was failed to create because it had a foreign key with invalid value. So we need to find out whether Django/Python has thrown the error due to model problems or your RDBMS has thrown the error due to integrity constraint violation.

Comment: when creating an appointment in the admin, were you able to select user,doctor,symptons, diagnosis as all these are another objects from other models?

Comment: @ray Yes i was able to select objects from the related models

Comment: @LajosArpad how do I find out where the problem is coming from?

Comment: Since I'm not a Django or Python specialist, I do not know. But I'm sharing the knowledge about how you can find out based on my experience with other tech stacks. You have an error message, which complaints about integrity constraint violations. So, it would be great to find out what the stack trace of your error is.

Comment: @ ray I just added screenshots of my attempt to create the appointment object

Comment: Sure thing. Your second screenshot is showing the stack trace (it's better to add the pictures into the questions rather than links to them, as links will die out over time and then your links will point nowhere). What do you have at base.py line 306?

Comment: @LajosArpad After a little bit of research on how to add the pictures directly, I don't think I have enough reputation points to add the pictures without the link being included.
Nevertheless, the base.py line 306 code is 'return self.connection.commit()' but it is inside a 'commit' function:

`
def _commit(self):
        if self.connection is not None:
            with self.wrap_database_errors:
                return self.connection.commit()
`

Comment: Okay. Can you somehow get the raw query that is to be executed from there?

Comment: I just figured it out. I deleted the migrations files, the pycache folder and the database. It's working now.